# If $f$ is a finite Blaschke product then $f'(z) = 0$ if and only if $f'(\frac{1}{\bar{z}}) = 0$

Tags: complex-numbers, blaschke-products

How can I prove "if $f$ is a finite Blaschke product then $f'(z) = 0$ if and only if $f'(\frac{1}{\bar{z}}) = 0$"?

A finite Blaschke product $f$ is a function of following type:
$$f(z) = \alpha z^m \prod_{k=1}^{n} (\frac{z-z_k}{1-\bar{z_k}z}), |z_k| \not = 1$$

Comment: What about induction?

Comment: @LucasHenrique induction on n?

Comment: Yes. You can describe this Blaschke product in terms of a rational function times another Blaschke product. Using induction, you can simplify the painful product rule

Comment: @LucasHenrique thanks a lot, it works :)